# Wrong date in tooltip in charts with daylight savings time in highcharts

Tags: javascript, date, highcharts

I have a chart with dates where one of the days is a daylight saving day. All days after this day have there date in the tooltip shifted by minus one day.

```
$(function () {
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
      useUTC: false
    }
  });
  $('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    chart: {
      type: "column"
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: "normal"
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: [{
        y: 10
      }, {
        y: 20
      }, {
        y: 10
      }],
      pointInterval: 86400000,
      pointStart: 1414274400000 //Sun Oct 26 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
    }]
  });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bmmg8jnx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is a date saving day?

Do you mean daylight savings time?

That would make sense, if you are sending a time stamp of midnight, and it loses an hour, then it will read as the previous day.  You can work around this by sending a stamp that is later in the morning, or at noon, or whatever point you like that is not at the start/end of the day, and therefore won't be affected by shifts of one hour.

{{edit to reflect comments:

1) the tooltip does reflect the value of the x axis. Notice that the point is not actually on the tickmark. Tickmarks are not placed to match your data points, they are placed at set intervals. Your data is behind that interval by an hour, and therefore the tooltip is properly reflecting the date of the data point.

2) an offset of this nature usually doesn't affect anything. Unless your data points are actually representing an even that happens every night at midnight, which is very rarely the case in any data I've seen or used.

If the data you are sending is off by an hour, then it's going to be off by an hour, and if that hour pushes the time into the previous day, your date is going to be off by a day. The chart is handling it all correctly based on what you have provided it.

Comment: Yes, daylight savings time. But adding an offset is not really an option. Also the tooltip should reflect the value of the xAxis.

Comment: 1) the tooltip does reflect the value of the x axis. Notice that the point is not actually on the tickmark. Tickmarks are not placed to match your data points, they are placed at set intervals. Your data is behind that interval by an hour, and therefore the tooltip is properly reflecting the date of the data point.  2) an offset of this nature usually doesn't affect anything. Unless your data points are actually representing an even that happens every night at midnight, which is very rarely the case in any data I've seen or used.